# Read a recipe to an array

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I am trying to create a recipe site and I have hit a wall.  I have recipes in .txt files in one directory and I need to scan the directory, read and store the ingredients (Flour, eggs, Milk etc) in an array, and also include the amounts of each so that they can be compared to what is requested by the user.  I have got a section that scans the directory and lists thumbnails of the available recipes but I cannot think how to set the arrays so that I can list each item to an `Onclick` event that adds so much of each to a bowl.  I don't want the quantities displayed, they are only for cross reference towards the end.

An example recipe file:

```
 • 250g plain flour
 • 50g icing sugar
 • salt
 • 1 lemon
 • 125g butter
 • 1 large egg
 • a splash of milk for the filling
 • 5 large apples
 • 3 tablespoons sugar
 • ½ teaspoon ground ginger 
 • a handful of sultanas 
 • ½ a lemon
```

To scan and display the available recipes I have:

```
<?php 

    $count = 0;
    $recipes = opendir('Recipes'); 
    while (false !== ($recipe = readdir($recipes))) {
        if($recipe != "." && $recipe != "..") {
            $value = str_replace(".txt","",$recipe);
            
            echo  '<td> <img src="../Recipe/Images/'; 
            echo $value;
            echo '.jpg" width="50" height="50" onclick="show(\'';
            echo $value;
            echo '\'); $recipe; return false"; alt="';
            echo $value;
            echo '" /></td>';
            $count++;
        }
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';
    
    echo '<p>You have '.$count .' recipes to chose from</p>';
    closedir($recipes);
?>
```

Can anyone point me right please?

Comment: Would help if we could see the contents of one of these text files..

Comment: This is one, and they are all set out in the same way.

Comment: • 250g plain flour
• 50g icing sugar
• salt
• 1 lemon
• 125g butter
• 1 large egg
• a splash of milk

for the filling

• 5 large apples
• 3 tablespoons sugar
• ½ teaspoon ground ginger
• a handful of sultanas
• ½ a lemon

Comment: That is all that is in the file.. no instructions?

Comment: I havent put any instructions in as yet, but was thinking it would be easier with them in a seperate file? I just need to add the temperature of 180C and a cooking time of 40 minutes.

Comment: Do you control what is put in the .txt files? - And why are you using .txt files?

Comment: Yes I do control what is in them.  I am just starting out, and havent even thought about touching a database as yet.  I need to get my head around the basics before I leap even further into the unknown as it were.  Once I have done it this way I will look at redesigning using a database as I know that way is better.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into the question, rather than leaving them as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.